# Proof: $a = b \vdash f(a) = f(b)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

How can I show:
$a = b \vdash f(a) = f(b)$, preferable in natural deduction.

I am allowed to use the following rules:

- all for propositional logic ($\land_i, \land_e, \lor_i, \lor_e, \rightarrow_i, \rightarrow_e, \lnot_i, \lnot_e, \lnot \lnot i, \lnot \lnot e$
- predicate logic: $=_i, =_e, \forall_i, \forall_e, \exists_i, \exists_e$

Comment: That depends on the precise rules you have -- the name "natural deduction" by itself is not enough to tell how your system handles such details. Usually this entailment, or something closely equivalent to it, will be a _primitive rule_ of the system. Or, if you don't have any rules that mention equality specifically, it may be handled as a non-logical axiom.

Comment: I'm refering to the rules for predicate logic...actually it is about the following exercise I'm trying to solve: Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, Mathematical Logic (2007), page 127, ex 5.4.5
I'm trying to prove the rule I'm going to use later. Maybe there's a proof without natural deduction?

Comment: There are several slightly different ways to set up natural deduction rules for predicate logic, and the differences matter here. You need to **show the actual rules in your question** -- though if you're too lazy to do that you can also just edit the reference to your textbook into the question and hope that someone who has that particular book comes by. But that will significantly reduce your chances of getting a answer tailored to the particular system you're working in.

Comment: ...actual rules are the rules I am allowed to use?

Comment: The actual rules are the rules of the system you want the proof to be conducted in. You have told us the name of that system, but the _name_ is not enough for a reader to be able to guess what its rules are.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to follow you. I just want to find an argument for that...

Comment: As long as you're keeping it secret which rules you want that argument to use, nobody here will be able to help you. Except people who have the particular textbook you've referenced, of course. But I don't see why you'd want to _limit_ the people who can help you that way.

Comment: Now I stated it.

Comment: The needed rules are : ($=$-intro) : $\vdash t=t$, where $t$ is a *term*, and ($=$-elim) : from $s=t$ and $\phi[s/x]$, derive : $\phi[t/x]$, with $s,t$ *terms* substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$, and $\phi$ a *formula*. The proof requires only to find a suitable $\phi$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what all your abbreviations mean, but here is how I would do it using standard logic. Assuming $f, a$ and $b$ had already been introduced...

1. Suppose $a=b$
2. $f(a)=f(a)$ by symmetry of equality
3. $f(a) = f(b)$ by substitution
4. We conclude: $a=b \implies f(a)=f(b)$

Comment: Can you explain step 3?

Comment: We substitute '$b$' for the right most occurrence of '$a$' in (2).

Comment: Thank you. This was what I wanted (too simple...)